# react native ReferenceError: Can't find variable: con

Tags: react-native

for two days searching for this issue can find any misspelling word

> con
> react antive 0.63.4
> no issues in build or run-android

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the issue was in vscode because its not found by vscode search,its not indexing characters very well,
so  ***con***  not a variable its just missing characters i found it by removing and re-adding the code files until found the line and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this command? If there is a problem with your code it will explain and tell you the details. this is the issue

Android:

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

IOS:

```
npx react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```