# Unable to install to real device after upgrade react native version form 0.64 to latest version

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone, react-native

My app needs to upgrade to react native, so I used npx react-native upgrade to upgrade it to the latest version. After the upgrade, I got react-native version 0.72.7 and tried to install it on the IOS 15.5 simulator, and it worked successfully. After that, I try to install on a real device (7plus, IOS 15.7.2) but it throw an error

```
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-11-27 04:01:06 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
No code signature found.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 364477;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE800801C)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000118c24c90 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 235
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000118c612ee __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010dde31c9 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000118c61016 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1409
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011a462888 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301 + 3520
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010df18769 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010df1927d __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 196
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81672d0cc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81672e317 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff816734317 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff816734dfd _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81673eeee _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 753
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8168e1fd0 _pthread_wqthread + 326
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8168e0f57 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone9,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.7.1 (19H117)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 10192;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620388";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.6 (Build 21G115)
Xcode 14.0.1 (21336) (Build 14A400)
Timestamp: 2023-11-27T11:01:06+07:00
```

Does any one know how to deal with this error? I have tried to set the framework to embed and sign, but nothing happened.

Comment: show me Xcode error (image)

Comment: The error I posted is full error message when building with xcode, so I think the xcode error image is unnecessary

Comment: Ok, try the link command below and let me know what happens

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77285785/11762907

Comment: thank for helping I decide to starting a new project for long term